# Set of Sylow subgroups of a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, $p$ a prime dividing the order of $G$, and let $S=\{ P: P \text{ is a Sylow }p \text{-subgroup of }G\}$. Let $x\in G.$ Then $S=S^{x}.$

Proof. Since the elements of $S^{x}$ are Sylow subgroups of $G$, then $S^{x} \subseteq S$ .Define the function $f:S \rightarrow S^{x}$ by $f(P)=P^{x}$. Let $P_{1}, P_{2}$ be elements of $S$.

$f$ is well defined.
If $P_{1}=P_{2}$, then $P_{1}^{x}=P_{2}^{x}$ and so $f(P_{1})=f(P_{2})$.

$f$ is one-to-one.
If $f(P_{1})=f(P_{2})$, then $P_{1}^{x}=P_{2}^{x}$ and so $P_{1}=P_{2}$.

$f$ is onto.
Let $P^{x} \in S^{x}$. Then we have $P \in S$ such that $f(P)=P^{x}$.

Thus $S=S^{x}$

Is the above true?

Comment: To me it seems that you have shown that $S$ and $S^x$ have the same cardinality (same number of elements) by constructing a bijection between $S$ and $S^x$, but this is not enough (and not needed at all for the proof) for the equality $S = S^x$. What you need to show is that every element of $S$ is in $S^x$ and conversely, every element of $S^x$ is in $S$. Then the two sets are equal.

Comment: @m.k.: Since the elements of $S^{x}$ are Sylow subgroups of $G$, then $S^{x}\subseteq S$. By the above proof $|S^{x}|=|S|$ and so we must have $S^{x}=S$.

Comment: Another approach is to map $S^x$ back to $S$ by the map taking any $P$ to $P^{x^{-1}}$, which is inverse to the map taking $P$ to $P^x$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, because of the finiteness, if you have a bijection and $S^x\subseteq S$ then it indeed follows that $S^x=S$.

Probably, it's simpler to argue further that $S^{x^{-1}}\subseteq S$, and now using your bijection $f$, we get $S=\big(S^{x^{-1}}\big)^x \subseteq S^x\subseteq S$.